# как типизировать возвращаемый результат

Tags: javascript, typescript

отметил место где не могу понять какой тип поставить потому как вoзможных вариантов возврата несколько либо TUser или TAddress или обе разом или null в типе Promise.all

и буду рад замечаниям на счет кода

```
    type TUser = {
        name: 'a',
        surname: 'b'
    }

    type TAddress = {
        address: 'x'
    }
    const getList = async (resource: string, params: GetListParams) => {
    const finishedResult = {
        data: [],
        total: 0,
    };
    const {body: { result, totalCount }} = await CustomerService.getCustomerPage()
    finishedResult.total = totalCount
    //вот тут каким будет возвращаемый тип?
    const promises = result.map(({addressId, userId}):какой возвращаемый тип? => {
        if(!addressId && !userId) {
            return null
        }
        if(addressId && userId) {
            return Promise.all([
                UserService.getUserById(userId),
                AddressService.getAddressById(addressId)
            ])
        }
        if(!addressId) {
            return Promise.all([UserService.getUserById(userId)])
        }
        if(!userId) {
            return Promise.all([AddressService.getAddressById(addressId)])
        }
    })
    promises.filter(e => e !== null)
    //вид данных внизу
    const res = await Promise.all(promises)
    res.forEach(arr => {
        let finalRes = {}
        arr.forEach(({status, body}) => {
            if(status === 'success'){
                finalRes = {...finalRes,...body}
            }
        })
        if(isObjectWithProperties(finalRes)){
            finishedResult.data.push(finalRes)
        }
    })
    return Promise.resolve(finishedResult);
}
```

данные в res

```
const res = [
[
    {
        status: '',
        body: {}
    },
    {
        status: '',
        body: {}
    },
],
[
    {
        status: '',
        body: {}
    },
    {
        status: '',
        body: {}
    },
],
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По коду - зачем мешать Promise и async\await? Используйте что-то одно.

Тип можете указать как `Promise<(TUser | TAddress)[] | null>`.
Или, если более точно `Promise<[TUser | TAddress, TUser | TAddress] | null>`

```
type TUser = {
    name: 'a',
    surname: 'b'
}

type TAddress = {
    address: 'x'
}

const func = async ():Promise<(TUser | TAddress)[] | null>=>null;
~ async function(){
const res = await func();
}();
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AVAqgZxgJ2AXmAbwFCiHAB2AhgLYwBcwA5KbQDQFEjICuaZlNtARrRYgAvniHhoceAEEAJrLQxkyLLnGFS8xct4APQYVHiAxgHtiyMMABm7YsdWlkEe8AAUASioAFNKfIAlqgAPG5IqBgAPghyCkrIHgDaALrA0cTsADaZAHyYORnZANziAH7ATi4OtvZgAeae+IRmFlbajgDupAFWNcaeJYYDQA